# Why this JS function does't not work when it calls by selenium.getEval()

Tags: javascript, selenium

Below js function is working well in html page. But when i put it into selenium.getEval in RC to wonder to get return value j. It cannot work, also without any error. Do i miss some function call format? Thanks in advance!!!

```
    function GetTableRow() 
    {
        var table;
        var ctext = "bb";
        var cname = "mps_tableborder"; 
        var col = 0; 
        var j;
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("table").length; i++) {
          if (cname==document.getElementsByTagName("table")[i].className) {
            table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[i]; 
            break;
          } 
        } 
        for (j = 0; j < table.rows.length; j++){ 
          if (ctext == table.rows[j].cells[col].innerText){ 
            break;
          }
        } 
        return (j);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide only the contents of method. Not the entire method. Try by removing the method starting [ function GetTableRow() {  ] and method ending [ } ] and give it to getEval method and see what it returns! Ideally it should work fine.